# Lucene search backend

Tags: lucene

I am going to work on search functionality by using Lucene. This is my first time using lucene, so I read some documentation, but i need some advice from people who already experienced the Lucene.

Lucene creates index files in a directory. I have four servers. But what is not clear to me is if the index files(located in a shared network directory) can be shared among four servers by using 'IndexSearcher' object when search request is made. I am wondering if there is no latency if the index files are shared.  Or do i need to create index files in each server?

And also how does the Lucene handle synchronization? let's say that backend process updates index files while search request is made.

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't lucene support concurrency between IndexSearcher and IndexWriter?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is a search library.  It knows how to search very well, but generally doesn't provide a lot of functionality on handling concurrency, or otherwise managing requests from multiple sources, outside of good practice thread-safety, and that sort of thing.  It generally falls to you to handle concurrent requests, and such.  Raw Lucene can be a good choice for incorporation into an existing service codebase, particularly.

For a full-featured Lucene-based search server that you can just setup, route requests to, and it handles that sort of thing for you, you should look into either [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)